# Pattern for implementing sync methods in terms of non-parallel Task (Translating/Unwrapping AggregateExceptions)

Tags: c#-4.0, asynchronous, exception, task-parallel-library

I have an Async method returning a Task.

I also wish to offer a synchronous equivalent, but I don't want consumers of it to have to go unpacking `AggregateException`s.

Now I understand that the whole idea is that you couldn't arbitrarily pick one in a general way, and I know I could go read loads more Stephen Toub articles (I will, but not now) and I'll understand it all and can decide for myself.

In the interim, I want to use the fact that my tasks are actually just chained 'workflows' without parallelism, just intervening Waits (no, not TPL DataFlow) which shouldnt not result in more than one exception. In that case, would it be appropriate to handle as follows:

```
    CallAsync().Wait();
}
catch( AggregateException ae)
{
    throw ae.Flatten().First()
```

or am I guaranteed that an `AggregateException` always has an `InnerException` even if there are more than one. Or is there a case where I should fall back to `.Flatten().First()` ?

---

In some TPL docs, I see a reference to an `Unwrap()` method on `AggregateException` (not sure if it was an extension or something in a beta release).

As a placeholder, I'm doing:

```
void Call( )
{
    try
    {
        CallAsync().Wait();
    }
    catch ( AggregateException ex )
    {
        var translated = ex.InnerException ?? ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions.First();
        if ( translated == null )
            throw;
        throw translated;                 }
}

Task CallAsync(){ ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no "clean" way to do this that I know of. You can't use `throw someInnerException;` because you'll lose the stack wherever the exception originated in the the async workflow and if you just use `throw;` you're obviously going to propagate the `AggregateException`. What you would have to do for the synchronous method is have some kind of "wrapper" exception that you can stuff the first exception of the `AggregateException` into and then throw that consistently from the synchronous version of the method.

```
void Call()
{
    try
    {
        CallAsync().Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        throw new MyConsistentWrapperException("An exception occurred while executing my workflow. Check the inner exception for more details.", ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions.First());
    }
}
```

FWIW, they've solved this in 4.5 with [the new `ExceptionDispatchInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will help you marshal exceptions across threads without whacking the stack. Then you could write the synchronous version like this:

```
void Call()
{
    try
    {
        CallAsync().Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions.First()).Throw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; especially for the stack loss point which I had considered and then turned a blind eye to (don't even know if normal PreserveStackTrace trick would work as I'm under medium trust so cant even try). Final question though (and my real starting point) - any idea why most samples use `.InnerException` instead of `.Flatten().InnerExceptions.First()` or some other way of unwrapping -- **are they equivalent or not** ? If so, any references? Are there other ways of unwrapping - any links appreciated...

Comment: If you take a look at the AggregateException constructors with ILDasm you'll see that there's ultimately a private constructor of (string, IList<Exception>) which is delegated to by the other implementations and in that constructor they call the base Exception constructor passing the first exception in the IList<Exception> as the innerException parameter. However, since the first exception COULD technically be another AggregateException, using Flatten() is the guaranteed way to get at the first non-AggregateException underlying exception.

Comment: Cool, that's explained it perfectly.  I wish one of the 50 pages of docs and articles could explain it as succintly. (I have yet to have at TPL w/ a decompiler - for some reason I consider it mentally off limits. As for how I explain not taking that attitude to WCF... :D)

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20279286/499721) is an implementation of `ExceptionDispatchInfo` for .Net 4.0