# Calling an async method from a synchronous method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I am attempting to run async methods from a synchronous method.  But I can't *await* the *async* method since I am in a synchronous method.  I must not be understanding TPL as this is the fist time I'm using it.

```
private void GetAllData()
{
    GetData1()
    GetData2()
    GetData3()
}
```

Each method needs the previous method to finish as the data from the first is used for the second.

However, inside each method I want to start multiple `Task` operations in order to speed up the performance.  Then I want to wait for all of them to finish.

GetData1 looks like this

```
    internal static void GetData1 ()
    {
        const int CONCURRENCY_LEVEL = 15; 
        List<Task<Data>> dataTasks = new List<Task<Data>>();
        for (int item = 0; item < TotalItems; item++)
        {
            dataTasks.Add(MyAyncMethod(State[item]));
        }
        int taskIndex = 0;
        //Schedule tasks to concurency level (or all)
        List<Task<Data>> runningTasks = new List<Task<Data>>();
        while (taskIndex < CONCURRENCY_LEVEL && taskIndex < dataTasks.Count)
        {
            runningTasks.Add(dataTasks[taskIndex]);
            taskIndex++;
        }

        //Start tasks and wait for them to finish
        while (runningTasks.Count > 0)
        {
            Task<Data> dataTask = await Task.WhenAny(runningTasks);
            runningTasks.Remove(dataTask);
            myData = await dataTask;


            //Schedule next concurrent task
            if (taskIndex < dataTasks.Count)
            {
                runningTasks.Add(dataTasks[taskIndex]);
                taskIndex++;
            }
        }
        Task.WaitAll(dataTasks.ToArray()); //This probably isn't necessary
    }
```

I am using await here but get an Error

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider
>   marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return
>   type to 'Task'

However, if I use the async modifier this will be an asynchronous operation. Therefore, if my call to `GetData1` doesn't use the await operator won't control go to GetData2 on the first await, which is what I am trying to avoid?  Is it possible to keep GetData1 as a synchronous method that calls an asynchronous method?  Am I designing the Asynchronous method incorrectly? As you can see I'm quite confused.

This could be a duplicate of [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9343594/2145211)  However, I'm not sure how to apply the solutions provided there as I'm starting multiple tasks, want to `WaitAny`, do a little more processing for that task, then wait for all tasks to finish before handing control back to the caller.

**UPDATE**

Here is the solution I went with based on the answers below:

```
    private static List<T> RetrievePageTaskScheduler<T>(
        List<T> items,
        List<WebPageState> state,
        Func<WebPageState, Task<List<T>>> func)
    {
        int taskIndex = 0;

        // Schedule tasks to concurency level (or all)
        List<Task<List<T>>> runningTasks = new List<Task<List<T>>>();
        while (taskIndex < CONCURRENCY_LEVEL_PER_PROCESSOR * Environment.ProcessorCount
            && taskIndex < state.Count)
        {
            runningTasks.Add(func(state[taskIndex]));
            taskIndex++;
        }

        // Start tasks and wait for them to finish
        while (runningTasks.Count > 0)
        {
            Task<List<T>> task = Task.WhenAny(runningTasks).Result;
            runningTasks.Remove(task);

            try
            {
                items.AddRange(task.Result);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                /* Throwing this exception means that if one task fails 
                 * don't process any more of them */

                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853693/pattern-for-implementing-sync-methods-in-terms-of-non-parallel-task-translating
                System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(
                    ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions.First()).Throw();
            }

            // Schedule next concurrent task
            if (taskIndex < state.Count)
            {
                runningTasks.Add(func(state[taskIndex]));
                taskIndex++;
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
```

Comment: The `Task` type has two completely different use cases: asynchronous work (e.g., `async`/`await`) and parallel processing (e.g., `Task.Factory.StartNew`/`Task.WaitAll`). What kind of work are you doing (i.e., is it CPU-bound)?

Comment: I am retreiving a web page (I/O bound) and then processing it CPU bound.  The MyAsyncMethod is constructed using two awaits one for the IO bound work and one for the CPU bound work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Task<TResult>.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) (or [`Task.Wait()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.wait.aspx) when there's no result) is similar to `await`, but is a synchronous operation. You should change `GetData1()` to use this. Here's the portion to change:

```
Task<Data> dataTask = Task.WhenAny(runningTasks).Result;
runningTasks.Remove(dataTask);
myData = gameTask.Result;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping a newbie.  This looks like a great solutions and certainly fixes my compile error.  I assume you removed the `Task.WaitAll(dataTasks.ToArray());` as you agreed it wasn't necessary since when all of the WhenAny are completed this is guaranteed to already have happened.

Comment: @Harrison actually, I was just highlighting the part where you had `await`, but now that you mention it, I think you're right about that.

Comment: if I am return the result from the function, Can I directly do   `return  Task.WhenAny(runningTasks).Result.Result` ?

Comment: If experiencing UI deadlock: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485115/synchronously-waiting-for-an-async-operation-and-why-does-wait-freeze-the-pro

Answer (score 9):

First, I recommend that your "internal" tasks not use `Task.Run` in their implementation. You should use an `async` method that does the CPU-bound portion synchronously.

Once your `MyAsyncMethod` is an `async` method that does some CPU-bound processing, then you can wrap it in a `Task` and use parallel processing as such:

```
internal static void GetData1()
{
    // Start the tasks
    var dataTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, TotalItems)
        .Select(item => Task.Run(() => MyAyncMethod(State[item]))).ToList();

    // Wait for them all to complete
    Task.WaitAll(dataTasks);
}
```

Your concurrency limiting in your original code won't work at all, so I removed it for simpilicity. If you want to apply a limit, you can either use `SemaphoreSlim` or TPL Dataflow.

Comment: You're closing over the loop variable when you likely didn't mean to.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In reading Implementing the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177.aspx] it says "In the .NET Framework 4.5, use the static Task.Run method as a shortcut to TaskFactory.StartNew" for CPU bound work.  It sounds like you are recommending a different approach.  Am I understanding you correctly? Since my method is a hyrbid of CPU and I/O are you recommending me to split it in two? Also, can you explain why the concurrency limiting won't work?  Thanks again.

Comment: You stated that `MyAsyncMethod` has a CPU-bound portion, so you need to use `Task.Run`. However, you should use it when *calling* the method, not in its *implementation*. You don't need to split it in two, but you do have the (unusual) case of an `async` method that is also CPU-bound, so you should document it well. The concurrency limiting won't work because as soon as you call `MyAsyncMethod`, the method is already running.

Comment: @StephenCleary - Why is there a need for Task.Run in the Select? Why could it not just be `.Select(item => MyAsyncMethod(State[item]))`?

Comment: @sethflowers: The op indicated that `MyAsyncMethod` has a nontrivial CPU-bound portion and thus wanted it to run on the thread pool. This is the [complex use case of `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-even-in.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary - thanks - your blog post helped me to better understand the problem the OP was having.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the following:

```
GetData1().Wait();
GetData2().Wait();
GetData3().Wait();
```

Comment: Note that if there is a current `SynchronizationContext` defined this code will deadlock.