# Run a Task based async method synchronously on WP8

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, task

I am trying to run a task based async method synchronously on WP. After reading the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010337/calling-an-async-method-from-a-synchronous-method). I succeed do that, call a async method **from system library** synchronously.

However, there is not task bases async method for each API, especially in WP, such as *WebRequest.BeginGetResponse*. So I wrote a wrap like:

```
Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, 
        request.EndGetResponse, null);
```

And, what's ironic, when I try to call it synchronously from a UI thread (a little stange? I am just doing a test), my program is **stuck** in request.BeginGetResponse, and never go on.

But why? I use the same code to call a system api and my method. Is there any wrong in my code? or other something?

very thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into the [deadlock situation I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), where an `async` method is attempting to resume on the UI thread while the UI thread is blocked.

The best solution is to use "`async` all the way" - that is, change your synchronous calling method to be asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, you're right, very thank you.In fact I found the situation with async and UI is very dangerous for newcomers. I will follow your advice in the future development, very thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Task.Start like this:

```
var requestTask = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, 
      request.EndGetResponse, null);
```

If you want it to be synchonous (I use that term lightly because it's not actually synchronous) you can then wait on the task.

```
Task.Wait(requestTask);
```

I would also recommend you think about adding the [Async Nuget Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) then you can async and await this task.