# Problems running async method with return value synchronously in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm trying to write a hardware library in C# using the async / await features. For many operations, there will be two methods, one that runs asynchronously, and another one running the asynchronous method synchronously. For example, consider this:

```
public override bool ReferenceRun(bool positiveDirection) {
    var runTask = ReferenceRunAsync(positiveDirection);
    return runTask.Result;
}

public override async Task<bool> ReferenceRunAsync(bool positiveDirection) {
    String cmd = createAxisCommand(positiveDirection ? refRunPlusCmd : refRunMinusCmd);
    bool writeOK = writeToCOMPort(cmd);
    if ( !writeOK ) return false;
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        WaitForHalt();
        return setParameter(postitionParam, 0);
    });
}
```

Form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19010649/2380654) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343647/2380654) answers, I suspected that it was ok  to call `runTask.Result` in order to wait for the async method to complete and then retrieve the result. However, when I run the code, the call to `ReferenceRun` does never return. When I pause execution in the debugger, I can see that it hangs at the `return runTask.Result` statement.

What's going on here?

**Edit:**
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14485115/2380654), the requested behavior can be achieved like this:

```
public override bool ReferenceRun(bool positiveDirection) {
    var runTask = Task<bool>.Run(async () => { return await ReferenceRunAsync(positiveDirection); });
    return runTask.Result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ReferenceRunAsync`, when you use `await`, the current synchronization context (typically the UI thread's context) is captured, and the continuation (what follows the `await` instruction) is run on that synchronization context. But since you are synchronously waiting for the result in `ReferenceRun`, the thread is already busy and can't execute the continuation, so you have a deadlock. An easy fix is to call `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the awaited task to avoid capturing the context:

```
return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    WaitForHalt();
    return setParameter(postitionParam, 0);
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Anyway, in general you shouldn't expose a synchronous wrapper for an asynchronous method, or the other way round. See Stephen Toub's explanations:

- [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx)
- [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

Another issue with your code is that `ReferenceRunAsync` isn't really synchronous, because:

- `writeToCOMPort` is a blocking IO operation (just a guess from the name), so the `ReferenceRunAsync` method will block until that call is complete
- the rest of the method is just offloaded to a different thread, so there is no real benefit other than to avoid blocking the caller

In this case it would probably be better to just expose a purely synchronous method, and let the caller offload it to another thread if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override bool ReferenceRun(bool positiveDirection) {
var runTask = ReferenceRunAsync(positiveDirection);
runTask.Wait();
return runTask.Result;}
```

Try this. You need to start the task befor you can use the result.

Comment: I did try this; it didn't work. Thomas Levesque's answer clarifies why.

Comment: Indeed, but I think you should add the runTask.Wait to validate that the result is set befor returning it in ReferenceRun. Sorry Answer was supposed to be additional.

Comment: Actually yes, but afaik `Task.Result` is already waiting for the task to finish.